# 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.' saving image to anywhere not Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

Tags: vb.net, image, filestream

Hoping someone here can help me. I've read the many other similar questions on StackOverflow but haven't found an answer that works for me...

I have code that exports data into an excel report. Part of that code copies an image and places it into a folder just created on the desktop. Then also inserts that image into the excel report. There are two different ways data is exported. Users can export one item at a time, or an entire program of items. When exporting one Item a folder is created on the Desktop with the ItemID, and the image is saved in that folder. When exporting a program a folder is craeted on the desktop for the Program, another folder is created inside that folder for vendor, and anther inside the vendor forlder for the item; Then the image is saved in that item folder. The code works just fine When exporting only an item, but gives an error...

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

...on the first image save when exporting a program.

The code to Call the method when exporting one Item is...

```
    Rprt_ItemRFQ_Class.ExportRFQ(Itm_ItemIDCmb.Text, ItmKey, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), ProgKey)
```

The Code to Export a group of Items is...

```
    Dim SaveFold As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), ProgName, VendName)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(SaveFold)
    For Each RFQRow As DataRow In DS.RFQRequestForm.Rows()
        Rprt_ItemRFQ_Class.ExportRFQ(RFQRow.Item("ItemID"), RFQRow.Item("ItmKey"), SaveFold, ProgKey)

    Next
```

The Code being called is... (SaveFold is a class variable)

```
Public Shared Sub ExportRFQ(ItemID As String, ItmKey As Integer, StartPath As String, ProgKey As Integer)

    SaveFold = IO.Path.Combine(StartPath, ItemID)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(SaveFold)

    "I have cut out all the code for creating and formatting the excel sheet as it is not relevent"

    ImgLoad(ItmKey, ItemID)


End Sub

Public Shared Sub ImgLoad(ItmKey As Integer, ItemID As String)

    GetPrimImg.Fill(DS.GetPrimImage, ItmKey)

    Dim FileStr As String = DS.GetPrimImage.Rows(0).Item(0)
    Dim NewPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(SaveFold, ItemID & ".jpg")
    Dim fs As IO.FileStream
    fs = New IO.FileStream(FileStr, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim RFQImg As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
    RFQImg.Save(NewPath)
    Dim Wid As Integer = IIf(RFQImg.Width = 450, RFQImg.Width * 0.53333, RFQImg.Width * 0.24)
    Dim Hgt As Integer = IIf(RFQImg.Height = 450, RFQImg.Height * 0.53333, RFQImg.Height * 0.24)
    RFQImg.Dispose()
    fs.Close()

    xlWorksheet.Range("T1").Select()
    Dim P As Object = xlWorksheet.Pictures.Insert(NewPath)
    With P
        .Left = xlWorksheet.Range("T1").Left
        .Top = xlWorksheet.Range("T1").Top
        .Placement = ExcelVB.XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = True
        With P.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Width = Wid
            .Height = Hgt
            .IncrementTop(3.333228)
            .IncrementLeft(102.1872441)
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

The Error Occurs on the line

```
    RFQImg.Save(NewPath)
```

I have tried modifying what gets passed in as SaveFold from the program export, it works just fine if I pass in Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), but any other file path I pass in causes the error.

Comment: What context are you running this as?  Are you in a service or a web page or desktop application?

Comment: You dont need to create an image since you arent altering the image.  `File.Copy` is all you need (but that is not the best way to create a path - see also `Path.Combine`..  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You posted the code that works.  We can't see what did not work, that is not helpful.

Comment: *As long as the variable...* NO, this also works `Dim SaveFold = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "temp")` `Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveFold)` to save in Desktop\temp\, as do other directories in place of desktop. You need to provide more code (as Hans said, code which doesn't work!)

Comment: I have modified the question to hopefully explain better, sorry if sorta noobish. Hans & djv - That's great the code works for you you but it doesn't work for me. Plutonix - thanks for the Path.combine help, I've modified to include that. TJ - desktop application

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm kind of an idiot here. Someone saved the vendor name which was the VendName variable with a space character at the end. That is why I was getting the error. I added a trim to the variables and all is good now.